# Sms sending without MFMessgeViewController on ios 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

Anybody no to send sms programmatically in `iOS6`.Earlier I was using core telephony method to send SMS.It's working fine up to `iOS5` but on `iOS6` my code is not working.
I using following code:

BOOL success = [[CTMessageCenter sharedMessageCenter]  sendSMSWithText:@"Message" serviceCenter:nil toAddress:@"8800781656"];

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How you import CTMessageCenter header file.

Answer (score 0):

I would make an educated guess that Apple has closed a loop hole in their API.  They do not want applications to send SMS message in the background without the user knowledge.  On some mobile network each SMS message cost money.

Comment: It's okay Black but i have developed app and i am just stuck on ios 6 only.Please suggest or give code if it is possible.

Comment: Agreed to @Black Frog. Don't know your business logic, but if you can use third party SMS service(usually cost your money ;) ), it's just a call to the third party's API(Usually is a web API, means an HTTP request)

Answer (score 0):

```
// in .m file
-(void)textClicked

{


 controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];

 if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])

    {


       controller.body = @"Whatever you want";

   controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"", nil];

       controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;

       [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
      }


   }

  - (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result

  {

  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"MyApp" message:@"Unknown Error"
                                               delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];

switch (result) {
    case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
        NSLog(@"Cancelled");
        [alert show];
        break;
    case MessageComposeResultFailed:
        [alert show];

        break;
    case MessageComposeResultSent:

        break;
    default:
        break;
  }

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }



// in .h file

 import MessageUI/MessageUI.h
 and delegate for Sending Message is  MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate
```

Hope , This will help You.

Comment: I dont want to use message view controller.I want to send sms in background of app.

Comment: Sending sms in Background has been restricted by Apple. If you want to send sms through your app this is the only way of doing it.

Comment: There must be SOME way of doing it -- the biteSMS application for jailbroken iOS devices sends SMS (and iMessages) in iOS 6...it's just a matter of figuring out/asking how sending is performed.