# iOS 6 - ChatKit private API - send SMS

Tags: ios, api, sms, private

Has anyone managed yet to send an SMS from code without user interaction in iOS 6?

I think, the ChatKit private API has to be used to do this. However, it seems that Apple changed this API quite a lot in iOS 6. As a result, solutions like https://stackoverflow.com/a/11028230/1884907 don't work anymore on iOS 6 because of missing/changed classes.

(just in advance: yes, we all know that Apple rejects apps with private API, it's not for the app store)

Comment: Did you find a solution here?

Answer (score 1):

From another StackOverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662105/sms-sending-without-mfmessgeviewcontroller-on-ios-6): (Code from Kaushal Bisht)

```
// in .m file
-(void)textClicked

{


 controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];

 if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])

    {


       controller.body = @"Whatever you want";

   controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"", nil];

       controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;

       [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
      }


   }

  - (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result

  {

  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"MyApp" message:@"Unknown Error"
                                               delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];

switch (result) {
    case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
        NSLog(@"Cancelled");
        [alert show];
        break;
    case MessageComposeResultFailed:
        [alert show];

        break;
    case MessageComposeResultSent:

        break;
    default:
        break;
  }

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }



// in .h file

 import MessageUI/MessageUI.h
```

You can't send SMS messages in the background though. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm afraid this shows up the message view controller. The aim is to send an SMS without user interaction. It has to work somehow with the ChatKit API but I guess noone has found out how yet.

Comment: Like I said before, apple won't let you send it in the background, since the user needs to know what they're sending, since they will get charged for it, you have to send a message through a logged in email app or apple sms/imessage app. Sorry but it's for the safety of the user.

Comment: This regards to public apps in the App Store, and that's fine.
But I'm pretty sure that there has to be an inofficial way to do this using private API. For example, it is also possible to initiate and accept phone calls and hang up via private APIs. Of course, apps which use such APIs would not get approved for the App Store, so there is no problem for the users.
But it's important to know that not all apps which are developed are meant for public release in the App Store. Some are for company-internal purposes and that's the case why we need such functions and to know how to access them.